# Pickle messing up text

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

I have made an app that is a virtual contactbook (For my school project i have 1/2 made a virtual contact book). This contact book asks for your name when saving, after you have saved(or loaded a contactbookfile) it outputs your name wierdly e.g. my name is Eoin Mag Ualghairg but it outputs my name as gEoin Mag Ualghair

I am completely baffled by this and i do not know what fixes this

excuse me about the whole code and excuse my terrible code (p.s am 13)

```
appname = "amserlen Glantaf"
import pickle, tkinter, time
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
password = "a1Bc6x"
studentname = []
camau = []
homeworkdis=[]
pnote=[]
tnote=[]
master = []
rar = []

fwin = tkinter.Tk()
fwin.title("Login")
class oof(): #Transition between window 1 and 2
    def nwin():
        fwin.destroy()
        home.gui()



class filing():

    def load():
        Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
        filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
        pickleoff = open(filename, "rb")
        master = pickle.load(pickleoff)

        rar = master[0]
        for i in range(len(master[0])):
            studentname.append(rar[i - 1])
        rar = master[1]
        for i in range(len(master[1])):
            camau.append(rar[i - 1])
        rar = master[2]
        for i in range(len(master[2])):
            homeworkdis.append(rar[i -1])
        rar = master[3]
        for i in range(len(master[3])):
            pnote.append(rar[i - 1])
        rar = master[4]
        for i in range(len(master[4])):
            tnote.append(rar[i - 1])
        oof.nwin()
    def newfilemake(): #requires password so that pupils do not create new save files to remove camau.
        saveasfile = tkinter.Tk()
        explain = Label(saveasfile, text = "Please enter your name below:")
        name = Entry(saveasfile)
        explain.pack()
        name.pack()


        def saveasdo():
            studentname = name.get()
            Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
            filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
            print(filename)
            master = [studentname, camau, homeworkdis, pnote, tnote]
            picklingon = open(filename, "wb")
            pickle.dump(master, picklingon)
            picklingon.close()
            oof.nwin()
            saveasfile.destroy()
        goyesbut = Button(saveasfile, text = "Save as", command = saveasdo)
        goyesbut.pack()
class home():#Syling second window

    def addparentnote():
        woof = tkinter.Tk()
        woof.title("Add a parentnote")
        insertwow = Text(woof)
        insertwow.pack()
        def yeeyeejuice():
            insertowowrar = gowowoof.get(1.0, END)
            pnote.append(inserttowowrar)
        gowowoof = Button(woof, text = "Add Parentnote", command = home.yeeyeejuice)
        gowowoof.pack()
    def removeparentnote():
        #removes a parentnote
        print("Coming soon")
    def parentnote():
        #open a new window with password and then add/remove parentnote
        woodwaw = tkinter.Tk()
        woodwaw.title("Add/Remove parentnote")
        woodoof = Button(woodwaw, text = 'Add Parentnote', command = home)
    def addteachernote():
        print("Soon")#adds a teachernote
    def removeteachernote():
        print("Soon")#removes a teacher note
    def teachernote():
        print("Soon")#open a new window with password and then add/remove teachernote


    def adiocam():
        camau += 1        


    def gui():
        swin = tkinter.Tk()
        swin.geometry('600x600')
        swin.title('Home')
        name = Label(swin, text = studentname)
        caminfo = Label(swin, text = str(camau))
        homeworkyeet = Listbox(swin)
        for i in range(len(homeworkdis) -1):
            homeworkyeet.insert(i, homeworkdis[i])
        cpnote = Button(swin, text = 'Add/remove Parentnote', command = home.parentnote)
        ctnote = Button(swin, text = 'Add/remove Teachernote', command = home.teachernote)
        addcam = Button(swin, text = 'Add cam', command = home.adiocam)
        name.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
        caminfo.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E)
        homeworkyeet.grid(row = 10, column = 0)



new = Button(fwin, text = 'New file', command = filing.newfilemake)
new.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
load = Button(fwin, text = 'Load file', command = filing.load)
load.grid(row = 0, column = 10, sticky = E)
```

I would expect:
Eoin Mag Ualghairg
but I am getting:
gEoinMagUalghairg

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, and to programming in general ;-)

The reason why your name is changed by the program is in this piece of code:

```py
rar = master[0]
for i in range(len(master[0])):
    studentname.append(rar[i - 1])
...
```

Let's say that `master[0]` contains the name 'Alice', so `len(master[0]) == 5`. In this case, `range` returns the values 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. But you're subtracting 1 when accessing the data. So you're adding elements -1, 0, 1, 2 and 3 of the name. In Python negative indices are used to access data from the end. So `'Alice'[-1]` returns `'e'`. That's why the last letter of the name is copied first, and effectively moved to the start of the name (e.g. "Alice" becomes" eAlic").

So if you change `rar[i - 1]` into `rar[i]`, the letters of the name will be in the correct order. However, it is still stored as a list of characters instead of a string. This is probably not what you want, so you'll need some more changes.

NB: you don't have to use indices and `range` at all. In Python you could just write the following:

```py
for item in master[0]:
    studentname.append(item)
for item in master[1]:
    camau.append(item)
for item in master[2]:
    homeworkdis.append(item)
for item in master[3]:
    pnote.append(item)
for item in master[4]:
    tnote.append(item)
```

And that's not even necessary if you just want to load the data, instead of appending it. If you want to create new lists, you can just write:

```
studentname, camau, homeworkdis, pnote, tnote = master
```

That's a lot shorter and no names are shuffled or changed to a list ;-)

And finally an advice for the next time you encounter such a problem: try to isolate the problem to make it easier to understand. So for this question you could try to write a small test application where you just store some test data and try to read and print it (without any of the tkinter stuff). This makes it much easier to understand for yourself and for others. You will likely get better responses on Stack Overflow if you post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).